# How to test Woocommerce API in localhost?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have Woocommerce local project. I have created  REST API to access from outside. Before I put the site on live, want to test locally if those API's sending data accordingly.

I tried to access `http://myproject.test/wp-json/wc/v2/orders` here what I got

> {"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you cannot list resources.","data":{"status":401}}

I am on linux using Ngnix.

Comment: I know I need to use Customer Key and Customer Secret.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to the functions.php file of your active theme:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_rest_check_permissions', '__return_true');
```

This will allow unrestricted access to the WooCommerce API. Please remember to remove or comment out this line when deploying your website to a live production environment to ensure proper security settings for the API.

Answer (score 1):

After having your **consumer_key** and **consumer_secret**, you can use them to get the orders even in the localhost environment. Here is a JavaScript example for you. The key is including an authorization header in the request header like the following:

```
  const url = `${storeUrl}/wp-json/wc/v3/orders`;

  const base64Credentials = Buffer.from(
    `${consumer_key}:${consumer_secret}`,
  ).toString("base64");

  let result;
  try {
    result = await axios.get(url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${base64Credentials}`,
      },
    });
    const ordersList = { orders: result.data };
    res.status(200).send(ordersList);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```